# Gradle dependency management : use "sub project" if jar not resolved

Tags: gradle, groovy, dependency-management

I work in a quite complex environment and I would like to have a custom behavior to handle dependencies rather than the default one.

In few words if I request

```
configuration { 
      compile "myGroupId:MyArtifact:MyVersion"
}
```

if this version does not exist locally or remote (I'm using artifactory), the dependency resolve will fail (which is normal). But I would like to be able to switch to local sub projet ":MyArtifact"

I've tried lots of things with configuration capabilities but it's quite new for me and I'm a bit lost.

I would really appreciate a little help!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html)?

Comment: I do not know this gradle feature. As far as I quickly understand, it depends on a command line option, am I right ?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just depend on the subproject always? `implementation project(":my-library")`

Comment: I'm not in the "standard" gradle way of doing with subproject in a single git repo. Every subproject has a git repo. We have to handle it with super module capability. And furthermore it is quite usefull to use pre-builded jar rather than recompiling everything all the time.

Comment: About composite build : it seems that I can work with it. I would prefer to work in other way but that's already better !